# How to fix `Class 'Predis\Client'` not found in drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, phpredis

I have a project based on drupal 6. I installed php5.6 and redis and php-redis on ubuntu.
Now, when I run my project, faced 'Class 'Predis\Client' not found in'.

also my redis config in setting file is like this:

```
$conf['redis_client_interface']           = 'Predis';
$conf['cache_backends'][]                 = 'sites/all/modules/redis/redis.autoload.inc';
$conf['cache_class_cache']                = 'Redis_Cache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_menu']           = 'Redis_Cache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_drupal_get_filename'] = 'Redis_Cache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_bootstrap']      = 'Redis_Cache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_path']           = 'Redis_Cache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_field']          = 'Redis_Cache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_views']          = 'Redis_Cache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_admin_menu']     = 'Redis_Cache';
$conf['lock_inc']                         = 'sites/all/modules/redis/redis.lock.inc';
```

Comment: Does php-redis match installed php version? Did you enable the extension in php.ini

Comment: I install php-redis with `sudo apt install php5.6-redis`. I dont know how to enable the extension in php.ini.

Comment: You can check if its enabled by running ```php -m``` to enable it you would need to add ```extension=redis.so``` to your ```php.ini```

Comment: when run `php -m | grep redis`, there is only redis. is ti enough?

Comment: ```composer require predis/predis```

Comment: I run it, But dont different.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/redis/issues/2881131 this might be of help